# Accessing Android Geolocation API from C++

Tags: android, c++, geolocation

Still quite new C++ so please bear with me.

I have to create a class library for to get some geolocation information, basically the longitude and latitude plus checking if mock location is active.

This class library will be loaded on a separate project that is using a different language so I don't have to delve a lot deeper in C++.

Comment: You want to get longitude and latitude on Android device using c++? If so, you should use NDK.

Comment: [There is no direct C/C++ API for this](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html) ... so you have to use JNI and call java API

Comment: @Selvin, thanks for directing me to JNI. I tried to look up for some example and found this: https://github.com/cppformat/android-ndk-example

And whoever down-voted this is pretty stupid.